# What is the standard way to make a invoice system database tables?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm confused how to create tables for invoicing system, because when one invoice have more products, I can't repeat same invoice id for the each product in the invoice table as PK cannot repeat. so what is the concept followed to create tables in such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating three tables

1. For invoices (InvoiceId Primary Key)
2. For Products (ProductId Primary Key)
3. For invoice items which hold InvoiceId (FK Invoices), ProductID (FK Products)

This way data redundancy will be minimized.

Thanks!

Comment: According to standard database design, Can a table(invoice items) can exist without a PK?

Comment: Yes we can generate one primary key for Invoice items table too (like IDENTITY type column). But adding product id in invoice table may increase duplicate InvoiceId & customer details. Because one invoice may be generated against multiple products.

Comment: And then final form of invoice created by joining those two tables and deriving required information for the particular invoice id using join queries?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks bro.. and please note here @Aaron Bertrand answer, If I try his table, there will be an issue with 'invoiceDetailsId' as it repeats ah?? and this is why you suggested to avoid PK of 'invoiceDetailsId' in invoice details table? consider my this example  https://ibb.co/YRmXzH1

Comment: I don't think you need to have UnitPrice column in "Invoice details" table. By joining "Invoice details" with Products table you can get price of products. Products.UnitPrice   *    InvoiceDetails.Quantity.

Comment: I would disagree with that. Price can change often. You will want to record both. The price at the time of sale on the transaction, and the current price in the products table. You may even want to maintain that price history elsewhere too. If you do not do this, you will have no idea how your transactions were calculated previously.

Comment: Actually it was an accident I added 'UnitPrice' @Rajesh Ranjan

Comment: Yes, It is a point to consider when in case of discounts on different purpose @Jacob H

Comment: @JacobH Yes, in that case it would be good to store calculated value (total price of the product) instead of unit price. It'll help to reduce repetitive calculation and query processing cost.

Comment: I think you're really over-complicating things here on the low-level details of the design, but lumping unit price * quantity into a single value might not be the best. What if they have buy 3 get one free, or save 10% when you buy more than 5, there are all kinds of things where total price will hide away details that are important when the customer tries to return one...

Comment: Also, what happens if a customer were to buy multiple products at different prices on the same transaction (maybe one marked down, or discounted, and others are full price, or your invoice has multiple sales)? This complicates the design even more as you add additional edge cases. It's much simpler with @AaronBertrand example of 1:N invoice to details.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Let says Invoidedetails have unit price post 10% deduction & the offer was limited to 3 days, then how would you know that there was an offer of 10% discount on the product during the 3 days?

Comment: The simplicity & complexity of design depends on the requirement of business logics. And we are discussing business logics here. .. :)

Comment: The OP was asking for table relations. Not their entire business model and all business logic they'll ever have to consider. Be careful not to paint people into corners, was my point. Hiding/aggregating pieces of information that you don't know aren't important on their own is painting someone into a corner IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks! for your complement Aaron :)

Answer (score 2):

The route I have taken is to use a table for invoices, which cover the transaction data (customer, salesperson, date) and then a table for invoice items (itemID, quantity) which would have a foreign key to the invoice table. This would let you have as many items being attached to an invoice, and each invoice would still only have one record.

Comment: And then final form of invoice created by joining those two tables and deriving required information for the particular invoice id using join queries?

Comment: Yes. Essentially the query for the invoice would return all ItemIDs and quantities from the invoice items table, where they have the matching invoice id. That would be joined to the invoice table to gather the customer information that is attached to the invoice

Answer (score 2):

You would typically split this out into two tables. There is one master row per invoice, then a second table that contains all the child rows for the various products that make up the invoice. A simple start:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoices
(
  InvoiceID int PRIMARY KEY,
  CustomerID int, -- FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Customers...
  InvoiceDate date,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.InvoiceDetails
(
  InvoiceID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Invoices(InvoiceID),
  ProductID int, -- FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Products...
  Quantity int,
  ...
);
```

Comment: According to your InvoiceDetails table, if one customer buys more products, how to insert records in this table? because,  we can't repeat the PK of InvoiceDetailID for each product in InvoiceDetails table!

Comment: Please have look at this example @Aaron Bertrand  https://ibb.co/YRmXzH1

Comment: @Aaron Why do you need InvoiceDetailID to be the same? If one customer buys multiple products under a single invoice, *InvoiceID* will be the same. InvoiceDetailID is there simply to uniquely identify a row, in cases where future expansion of functionality might exist (consider the case where in one order I buy two razors and have one sent to my house and one sent to my dad - I need two detail line items, one for each address).

Comment: So you meant, InvoiceDetailID must be added but not necessary or we shouldn't include it in final form of generating invoice by joining two tables?
Please consider my example. https://ibb.co/BZJpGwL

Comment: IMO both PK's could be identities.

Comment: @Darko Sure, I was leaving implementation out, they could be identity, sequence, guid, manufactured externally, etc. How the PKs are created seems separate from the question.

Comment: @Aaron InvoiceDetailID does not need to be added, but you'll need some way to identify a row in the case where a PK on InvoiceID, ProductID is insufficient.

Comment: I got it, Thanks bro @Aaron Bertrand